# Return method, Calculation Error

Tags: java

I wrote the following program:

```
    public double calcElectricityCO2(double avgBill,                                         double avgPrice)
    {
        return (avgBill/avgPrice)*1.37*12;

    } 
    public static void main(String[ ] args)  
    {
        double avgBill = 338.59;
        double avgPrice = 0.12;
        double emmision = calcElectricityCO2(avgBill,avgPrice);
        System.out.printf("Annual CO2 Emission from Electricity Usage: %1.2f %n",emmision);
    }     
}
```

When run it reports an error on `double emmision = calcElectricityCO2(avgBill,avgPrice);` What did I do wrong there?

Comment: _What does the error say?_

Answer (score 8):

your `calcElectricityCO2` should be declared `static`.

```
 public *static* double calcElectricityCO2(double avgBill, double avgPrice){
    //implementation
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. As SLaks mentioned above, it would have been nice if you included the error (hover over the squiggly red line if you are using Eclipse or IntelliJ). Also, accepting satisfactory answers is a good practice.